# Why the result in matrix after softmax is 0 or 1 not in (0, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I tried use tensorflow to build Inception-v3 CNN to do audio classification, but it doesn't work, I found that the elements in result matrix after softmax are only 0 or 1, no other reuslts.
like this

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

sorry, forgot to post my code.
I have divided the audio into frames, each frame is 960ms

```
n_fft = int(window_length * sr) # window_length is 25ms, sr is the 
sample rate
hop_length = int(hop * sr) # hop is 10ms
feature = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=signal, sr=sr, n_mfcc=64, hop_length=hop_length, n_fft=n_fft)
```

this code will return a 64 x 97 matrix, which is my input of the CNN.
The inception model, I refered from https://github.com/tensorflow/models

```
# some parameters
leraning_rate = 3e-15
batch_size = 12
activation_fn = tf.nn.relu
trunc_normal = lambda stddev: tf.truncated_normal_initializer(0.0, stddev)
weights_initializer=trunc_normal(0.1)
```

Comment: What is your input and code?

Answer (score 0):

Because your model are 'confidence' for the classification. There are lots of reason will cause this situation occur, like 
1. Your activation function is not appropriate
2. The initialization of the weights or bias are too large
3. The learning rate is too fast
4. You may need less NN for the model.